# Chrome ignoring <button> css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Even the simplest custom button, such as 
    `<button class="button-new">Test button</button>`
shows up as the chrome default button. My button-new css looks like this:

```
.button-new{
  padding: 45px;
  border-color: black;
  background-color:#444;
  color: white;
}
```

I am using codepen.io, then uploading to a web-server using ftp. On codepen, it looks fine. When i visit the webpage, it ignores my styling, but only on the button.

The site is fsleague.website if you'd like to take a look for yourself.
Here is the site html, as it appears on the web:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>A Pen by  John Manos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style></style></head>

<body>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="well outter-well">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="text-center ubuntu-font"><strong>Fantasy Stock League</strong></h1>
                </div>
            <button class="button-new">Please work</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: @KodosJohnson just added it.

Comment: Is your css file being loaded? Check in browser inspect to see if your button class is being loaded or over-rided. I can think of no other circumstance where explicit classes are overruled by default

Comment: Please paste the code into the question and remove the picture reference to it.

Comment: Copy and paste this `<style>.button-new{padding: 45px;border-color: black;background-color:#444;color: white;}</style>` before the `</head>`. It should definitely work.

Comment: I added the name of the site so that you can visit it and see whats going on  for yourselves. @KodosJohnson shouldn't that just be in the css file, not the actual .html? Sorry, I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: It's good practice to put css in a css file, but right now we are debugging so you can put the css code in your html file to test.

Comment: Is your css code inside `style.css`? And is it inside a folder named `css` that is next to your html file?

Comment: Your styles are being applied as expected on your website. What's your problem? No default button styling for me (latest Chrome, Mac).

Comment: @KodosJohnson yes and yes

Comment: @connexo the styles are all there for me except the button has no styling. I'm on chrome on windows 10, my chrome has an update available but im fairly certain its nearly up-to-date

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @KodosJohnson putting the css into the html file worked. Im not sure why the problem occurs otherwise, nor how I can avoid it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing chrome's cache fixed the problem. I think the page was loading an old css file from the cache instead of loading any edited css file.

Comment: If this solved your question, you can mark your own answer as the answer to the question so others know.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Also when you're deploying publicly (production code), consider using a library like normalize.css. It'll reset all default browser applied styles and other inconsistencies for you. Load this BEFORE all your css:

[Normalize CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: I have tried -webkit-appearance: none; in the css class, and I just tried it again and it does not help. I will look into normalize.css

Comment: I included normalize.css and the problem still stands.